# Laplace inverse of $\sin/\cos$

Tags: laplace-transform

how would i go about finding the Laplace inverse of:

$$\frac{2s}{(s^2+5)^2}$$

Was hoping partial fractions would simplify this for me, but to no avail. I only have the Laplace transform of some basic functions to compare with:

$\sin$
$\cos$
$t^n$
$t$
$1$

It looks like a cosine but, solution says something else.

Comment: Hint: Convolution theorem

Answer (score 0):

You probably also know how what will happen when you differentiate a Laplace transform. Hint: what is the derivative of
$$
\frac{1}{s^2+5}\:?
$$

Comment: Ok, I see, is it possible to move the d/ds outside the laplace inverse? :)

Comment: @Böne No! But if $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$, then $F'(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $tf(t)$.